# How to get data when query select inner join many table in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

This is my project. I having problem, I want to get data from table Student join many table branch, room, and gender use annotation @Query as site query in the image MySql

[This is query with statement MySql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UMEd.png)

[This is code I want to use @Query in Spring Data JPA with purpose get data when join many table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6gJS.png)

After I call API, It notify error
[This is error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6K0bX.png)

I need to support, this is my project:
https://github.com/daovantam0410/quan-ly-dao-tao

Comment: Post your code here instead of attachments and images, it'll be more efficient and simple for us to test your code and help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here, you can use get the students from the database.

```
List<Student> students = studentRepository.findAll();
```

This will load the other entities (room, gender and branch) by issuing other queries and this will lead to the famous problem `N+1 queries`

So to load all the entities in one go, use `entity graphs` or `fetch join`

```
@Query(value = "SELECT st FROM Student st INNER JOIN FETCH st.branch b INNER JOIN FETCH st.gender g INNER JOIN FETCH st.room r")
List<Student> fetchStudentDataJoinTable();
```

**Note**: If the properties (`room`, `gender` and `branch`) can be `null` in student then use `left join` instead of `inner join`.

Comment: Hi @b.GHILAS, is there any way to get the first row along with this JPA inner join?